# Redux store does not match state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an icon that when clicked it triggers a function that calls an `API` and then **dispatch an action** to remove a blog post from the **state**. But the problem is that my UI does not re-render. However, if I refresh my browser the post that I deleted is no longer there and my store matches my **state**.

Here is my function that calls an `API` and then **dispatch an action**:

```
export function deletePost(postID) {
   return (dispatch) => {
      fetch(`${url}/posts/${postID}`, { method: 'DELETE', headers})
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((postID) =>  dispatch(removePost(postID)))
      .catch((error)=>{console.log('dispatch error',error)});
 };
```

Here is my **action**:

```
export function removePost ( postID ) {
 return {
  type: REMOVE_POST,
  postID,
 }
}
```

And here is my **reducer**:

```
function posts (state = {}, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
    case REMOVE_POST:
     return [
              ...state.filter((post)=>post.id!==action.postID)                  
           ];      
    default:
     return state
   }
 }
```

Now when I simply dispatch an action **without calling** an `API`

```
export function deletePost(postID) {
 return (dispatch) => {
   dispatch(removePost(postID));
 }
```

My state is correctly updated but of course my redux store is not. When I do the calling of `API` before dispatching an action as shown earlier, there is also no error coming from the `console` log.

What could be the problem here? I am very new to `ReactJS` and can't find a solution yet to this problem after many tries.

Also, as a note, I am using `redux-thunk` in this project.

Comment: Have you setup the redux dev tools?  If not it makes debugging much easier: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools If you are dispatching actions the state in your reducer *is* your redux store, the way you are using those words is confusing.

Comment: I have a `Redux` dev tools installed and as well as `React` dev tools.

Comment: If you are performing an asynchronous side-effect with your dispatched action you should be using [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). Also everything in @cfraser's post is correct as well you should probably have your initial state represent what your state will actually look like.

Comment: So do you see the REMOVE_POST action in the dev tools?  Is it successfully dispatched?

Comment: Yes, I could confirm that it shows on the Redux dev tools. Check on this [link](https://imgur.com/a/CUdJe).

Comment: I used `redux-thunk`.

Comment: You were already using it? What does your mapStateToProps look like can you post it?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few questions, but first: I think the problem is here:

```
[
  ...state.filter((post)=>post.id!==action.postID)                  
]
```

What is the state's shape? Is it `state = [post1, post2, ...]`? I can see the initial state is `{}`, so I find it weird to be calling `state.filter` and not `state.posts.filter` or whatever here.

The other might be problem, is with `post.id !== action.postID`, maybe the received ID is an `number` type, and maybe the local `id` is a `string`? Maybe the other way around?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That reducer works and UI updates when I remove the calling of an API. So, that means that's not the problem.

Comment: But what is the shape of the state? How are you reading the posts? They are stored at state's root? But whatever, you seem to know that the problem is anyway...

Comment: The shape of the state is simply `state = { posts: [] };`. I am able to get all the posts and display and also able to successfully add a post as well. I am very new to React, sorry if my answer or question, confuses you.

Comment: Yea but when you do filter your state becomes an array instead of an object if this is your root reducer.

Comment: If this is a post reducer and you are composing your root reducer from it then just change your initial state to be `[]` instead of `{ }` otherwise when you have no posts you won't be able to do things like check the length of the posts array because it will be an object.

Comment: This is my `rootreducer` and it goes together with other reducers and I did `combineReducer`.

Comment: @Edper it doesn't confuses me, but it someone asks you for more details about *your* original question trying to help you, maybe you shouldn't say that's nor relevant and you should instead give those extra details?